# Ricoh 5002 Turn off autoprint when faxes come in

Tags: printing, printer, fax

How do I turn off autoprint when faxes come in?

I'm reading the manual and it's not very succinct.

Model Ricoh Aficio 5002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where you change it (assuming you're in front of the machine):

1. Press the **User Tools** button, to the right of the keypad
2. Touch **Facsimile Features**
3. Touch **Reception Settings** (4th tab across)
4. Touch **Reception File Settings**

You'll have the option to disable printing there. If you get lost while having a look around, press **User Tools** again to bail out and start from the beginning.

Oh, and don't forget to enable fax forwarding or storing - if you do want to forward to an email, they'll need to be in the Address Book already.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ricoh support site you can disable fax printing by turning on Memory Lock Reception. That tells the printer to store faxes in memory until the Memory Lock ID code is entered from the front panel. You will need to set up the ID, as shown [here](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001042/0001042969/view/fax/int/0231.htm). You can also specify what is to happen with the received fax. It can be stored in memory for printing later, or forwarded somewhere else, e.g. an email address. All this (including disabling Autoprint) can be done at the [Reception File settings](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001042/0001042969/view/fax/int/0233.htm) page.

Comment: The Ricoh online manual ( http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/html/oi/re/model/mp42/mp42en.htm# ) seems excellent. I wanted to add it, but was only allowed to post 2 links.